# Can apache drill work with cloudera hadoop?

Tags: cloudera, apache-drill

I am trying to setup apache drill in distributed mode. I already have cloudera hadoop cluster with a master and 2 slaves. From documentation given on apache drill, its not pretty clear if it can be set up with typical cloudera cluster. I could not find any relevant articles. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working with cloudera hadoop distribution. I already had cloudera cluster installed with all services running.

perform following steps:

1. Install apache drill on all nodes of the cluster.
2. Run drill/bin/drillbit.sh on each node.
3. Configure storage plugin for dfs using apache drill webinterface  at host:8047. Update HDFS configurations here.
4. Run Sqlline :     ./sqlline -u jdbc:drill:zk=host1:2181,host2:2181,host3:2181
   (2181 is the port number used by zookeeper.)

Comment: Can you please post an example DFS configuration? In my scenario the JSON is accepted by the web interface but sqline doesn't seem to see those changes.

Answer (score 2):

Drill can be installed along with Cloudera on the nodes of the cluster independently - and would be able to query the files on HDFS. 
Refer the link for installation details - 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DRILL/Deploying+Apache+Drill+in+a+Clustered+Environment

Comment: That link is not public at present :\

Comment: This worked for me https://drill.apache.org/docs/installing-drill-on-the-cluster/

Answer (score 1):

It may only work with a rudimentary insecure cluster as Drill currently isn't tested / documented to integrate with HDFS + Kerberos for secure Hadoop clusters. Vote and check back on this ticket for Drill secure HDFS support:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3584